# PHP - How can I git aws.push to elastic beanstalk without restarting rds?

Tags: php, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

My end goal is to setup a **workflow** for Drupal 7 on an AWS EC2 instance that uses RDS for the database. I want to be able to run `git aws.push` without impacting my RDS instance *at all*.

### The Setup:

1. I cloned Drupal 7 to my local machine
2. I setup an Elastic Bean Stalk application, environment, and RDS instance in the web console.
3. I ran `eb init` inside the Drupal directory. Here's my /.elasticbeanstalk/config:

> ApplicationName=drupal
>
> AwsCredentialFile=/path/to/.elasticbeanstalk/aws_credential_file
>
> DevToolsEndpoint=git.elasticbeanstalk.[REGION].amazonaws.com
>
> EnvironmentName=[drupal-env]
>
> EnvironmentTier=WebServer::Standard::1.0
>
> EnvironmentType=LoadBalanced
>
> InstanceProfileName=aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
>
> OptionSettingFile=/path/to.drupal/.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.[drupal-env]
>
> RdsDeletionPolicy=Snapshot
>
> RdsEnabled=Yes
>
> RdsSourceSnapshotName=test-snapshot-1 Region=[REGION]
>
> ServiceEndpoint=https://elasticbeanstalk.[REGION].amazonaws.com
>
> SolutionStack=64bit Amazon Linux running PHP 5.3

1. I `git aws.push` and files are uploaded to Elastic Bean Stalk and everything seems to work.

### The Problem

Running `git aws.push` *also* restarts my RDS instance, causing data loss. What do I need to change so that I can run `git aws.push` without restarting/reloading my RDS instance?

Comment: Well, restart should not cause database to lose records, otherwise what's the point. And uniquely it was restarted. Are you sure that the new database is not recreated by startup script or the startup script in Drupal initializing the database?

Answer (score 2):

When you run >eb init, in one of the steps it will ask you if you want to create a new RDS instance, where you should answer no.